# Using binary numeric constants in MIPS asm source code?

Tags: assembly, binary, mips

On the process of learning Assembly i got one question

If i do the following:

```
la  $a1, 0x3f
```

The number 63 is loaded into a1.

And if I use a constant without a leading 0x it's decimal, giving the same result:

```
la  $a1, 63
```

But how can I handle binary? Lets say

```
la  $a1, 00111111
```

How can MIPS understand that 00111111 is the number 63 in binary?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Binary literal constants are not typically supported. What assembler are you using? If it supports C style preprocessing, there are several options available.

[Here](http://embeddedgurus.com/barr-code/2009/09/binary-literals-in-c/) is one example.