# How to represent binary numbers in mips ? Like hexadecimal we represent them with 0x

Tags: assembly, mips

```
.data
a: .word 0xFFFFFFFF
.text
main :
lw $v0,a
move $t1,$v0

andi $t2,$t1,0x00000080 
srl $t2,$t2,7

move $v0,$t2
li $v0,1

move $a0,$t2
syscall
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MIPS understand binary representation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9828251/mips-understand-binary-representation)

Comment: BTW, most of the time the hexa is enough, if you understand that each 4 bits form a single hexadecimal digit, it's not that difficult to do the conversion in head and read the hexa value as bit mask. For example the last byte of `0x00000080` is `0x80` and that's `1000 0000` binary (`1000 = 8, 0000 = 0`).