# In mips, is it possible to use a binary number instead of a decimal number for a constant?

Tags: mips

I know that 0x00039 tells the computer that you are working with hexidecimal and I'm wondering if there's a binary version of the 0x...

For example, can I do:
li $t0, 10001
and let the the program know that I mean 17 and not ten-thousand and one?
I tried doing 0b10001 but it gave me an error.

Comment: Are you in the same class as me? I am on week 4 of MIPS and have not been assigned a task to use binary number instead of decimal. All of the learning thus far have converted decimal-->binary, hex-->decimal, machine-->binary, binary-->decimal floating point, multiply binary etc. According to MIPS design Principle 3- good design demands good compromises (in regards to register and there are only 16 bits in constant or addresss, which means lit can load any word or word instruction up to 2^15

Answer (score 0):

According to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9828378/2624391) MIPS doesn't support binary, however, you might be able to [use C macros](https://embeddedgurus.com/barr-code/2009/09/binary-literals-in-c/) to emulate it.